# Stretched character spacing with url citation

Tags: spacing, urls, biblatex-chicago

When printing a citation with a long URL lacking good break points, in a wide text block, the character spacing gets stretched out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Example,
  author={Authorson, Author J.},
  title={Website},

  url={http://www.super-long.url/with/many/parts/that-should/runOverTheLine_AndCauseSpacingProblemsLikeThis}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
See the example.\autocite{Example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro `\biburlsetup` sets `\Urlmuskip` to `0mu plus 3mu`, which is responsible for the space stretching.

Here's a way for reverting the choice, but of course you'll get an underfull line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Example,
  author={Authorson, Author J.},
  title={Website},

  url={http://www.super-long.url/with/many/parts/that-should/runOverTheLine_AndCauseSpacingProblemsLikeThis}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\appto\biburlsetup{\Urlmuskip=0mu\relax}

\begin{document}

See the example.\autocite{Example}

\end{document}
```

[image]